# How to set default text in spinner?

Tags: android, mysql, spinner

I want to set default Text in Spinner & i am fetching all the data from the database mysql but i want to set one default Text like "Select Model" statically  can anyone help me for this??

i tried this also :-

```
sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    arraylist.add(0, "Select Item");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, listItems);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but it's not working
  please suggest me for this.

Comment: why dont you try this sp.setselection(0); Since you have added the Select item to the 0th position.This line will show 'Select Item' since its at the 0th postion. Try..!

Comment: nope i want to add statically the 1 item like "select model" it is not stored in the database want to just display..

Comment: statically meaning in the xml?

Comment: yes excatly..anywhere, i just want to display it on the screen..but not from the database.

Comment: <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/idSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="Select Item" />//this is your default value You can try this

Comment: giving error like Error:(25, 25) String types not allowed (at 'prompt' with value 'Select Item').

Comment: Try storing the value in the Strings.xml and referencing it, rather than giving directly android:prompt="@string/select_item"

Comment: nope it's not working too..